# WCF service client works on some systems - not on others

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

Disclaimer - I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to web services - especially when dealing with WS-Security.  This is my first post to stackoverflow - this site has helped me out countless times, but this time I'm in a real bind. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

I'm consuming a third party web service - started off by creating a C# test form and added a service reference (WCF) using a WSDL provided. The WSDL was for a lab environment and did not have the SSL endpoints required for my testing. Custom binding configuration details were provided and once added to app.config things worked as expected. I'm not certain the web service is WS-security complaint as claimed - was told that the security implemented is fairly basic, username over transport with SSL. As stated once I received the app.config with the custom binding things seemed to work.

Initial testing was on ws2008 and win 7 - I simply copied the contents of the debug folder generated by VS (.exe, .ddl, config file, etc) from system to system and ran the .exe of the test form I wrote. Things worked until I tried running the test app on a WS2008 with IIS7 installed. The serves only had roles and features installed needed for IIS and .net. Just to clarify I'm not hosting anything in IIS yet (that's part two) - just trying to run my test .exe on a server with the IIS role installed.

The error I received is:

```
 "An invalid security token was provided (An error happened processing a username token)"
```

I'm not certain that the presence of IIS is significant but it was the only thing installed on the server were things did not work. Can't help to think it's something environmental since it works on some systems but not others? I noticed that when the .net framework 3.5.1 role service is installed on WS2008 you don't see the framework in add and remove programs? Is there another role or feature I need to install/configure?

Thanks,
Joe